# 'aws ec2 describe-instances --query' doesn't work in ZSH

Tags: command-line, zsh, amazon-web-services

The following command works just fine in bash:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=XXXXXXX" "Name=instance-state-code,Values=16" \
  --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicDnsName'
```

However, if I try to run it in zsh, it gives me:

```
(eval):1: no matches found: Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicDnsName
```

Is there any way of working this around?

I'm running:

```
aws-cli/1.11.5 Python/2.7.6 Linux/4.4.0-45-generic botocore/1.4.62
```

Comment: Use double quotes around the query instead of single?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=XXXXXXX" "Name=instance-state-code,Values=16" \
  --query '"Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicDnsName"'
```

Brackets are a used for globbing in both *zsh* and *bash*. The difference is that by default *bash* leaves a pattern unchanged, if it does not match, while *zsh* prints a "no match found"-message.

Usually quoting them with single quotes - as done in question - should solve this issue. But it seems that at least the value of the option `--query` is run through `eval` without prior sanitation or extra quoting. You get the error message as the existing single quotes are not passed on as part of the value. In the solution I suggesed, the double quotes will be passed on, so that the query is still quoted when it is run through eval.

Comment: Double quotes was the only way to get --query working on Windows as well. Thanks.